# Debezium UI for nats jet stream

Tags: debezium, nats.io, debezium-engine, debezium-server, nats-jetstream

We are using NATS Jetstream for streaming messages from debezium connector. I want to create UI for debezium to see changes.

I have seen in the documentation about this
[link](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-ui.html), here they have mentioned only for apache Kafka like which has Kafka connector , but I want for NATS Jetstream. and wanted to like is debezium UI is compatible for that or only compatible with Kafka connector